# Code doesn't do anything when replacing Javascript with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript code:

```
var right = document.getElementById("true").checked;
var wrong = document.getElementById("false").checked;

if (right){
    answer += 100;
}
```

I want to replace the Javascript with jQuery, so I replaced this line:

```
var right = document.getElementById("true").checked;
```

with this:

```
var right = $('#true')[0].attr('checked');
```

I have also downloaded and added the jQuery file to my HTML:

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.2"></script>
```

However when I replaced the above JS code with jQuery it isn't working at all. What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT:** I have also tried this,

```
function calc(){
    $(function() {
        var isTrue = $('#true').attr('checked');    
    });

    var wrong = document.getElementById("false").checked;

    if (right){
        answer += 100;
    }
}
```

But it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using jQuery 1.9+ the attr('checked') gets the initial state of the checkbox when its state changes you need to use the prop() function.

```
$('#true').prop('checked');
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `[0]` accessor on the jQuery object returns the native DOMElement. This does not have an `attr()` method, so if you checked the console you'd most likely see an error.

In your case you should instead just call `attr()` (or better yet, `prop()`) on the object resulting from the selector. Also, don't forget to wrap your code in a document.ready handler. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    var right = $("#true").prop('checked');
    var wrong = $("#false").prop('checked');

    if (right){
        answer += 100;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you tell OP why he should use `.prop` instead of `.attr`? http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: @Rory, Should I just create this jquery function inside Javascript function ? Like i showed in my question ? (please see the edit)

Comment: @RileyWillow ah, if you are executing your code from a function, you do not need the `$(function() { })` wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var right = $('#true').attr('checked');
```

instead of

```
var right = $('#true')[0].attr('checked');
```

and you should use

```
var right = $('#true').prop('checked');
```

because `$('#true')[0]` returns you the DOM element and `.attr()` works with jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

ID is unique identificator. You should have only one unique ID in your HTML. That means, you don't need to put there array identificator. Do it like this:

```
var right = $('#true').attr('checked');
```